# .htaccess weird rewrite behaviour

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to mask the word 'links' in my urls.

I have the following code that rewrites well and the URL in the address bar is **not** changed if you visit this url directly:

```
http://url.com/posts
```

If the URL is from a link within the site () the url in the address bar is changed from

```
http://url.com/posts to http://url/links
```

Here is the Rewrite code I am using:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)posts(.*)$ /$1links$2 [P]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what is the rest of the url structure, and I'm not quite clear on what you are trying to achieve..

Comment: I'm masking the word 'links' in my urls with the word 'posts'. What I have above works well when you browse to http://url.com/posts the address in the address bar stays the same (http://url.com/posts). 

However, when you click on a link inside the the webside `<a href="http://url.com/posts">` for example, the URL is not masked and the address in the address bar is: http://url.com/links. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inserting this rule before your existing rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)links[^\s]* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1posts%2 [L,R,NE]

#existing rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)posts(.*)$ /$1links$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. When I use this, it says I have a redirect loop.. I can't work out why that might be?